# Error while running python program for spark streaming with kafka

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using latest spark (2.1.0) and python (3.5.3) installed. I have kafka (2.10.0) installed locally.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pykafka import KafkaClient
import json
import sys
import pprint 

spsc = SparkContext(appName="SampleApp")
stsc = StreamingContext(spsc, 1)
print('contexts =================== {} {}'.format(spsc,stsc));
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(stsc, "localhost:2181", "spark-consumer", {"7T-test3": 1})
spsc.stop()
```

Here 'print' line executes fine. But on next line while creating stream I get following error,

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MacAdmin/Downloads/spark-streaming/spark/spark_streaming_osample.py", line 24, in <module>
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer", {"7T-test3": 1})
  File "/Users/MacAdmin/Documents/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 70, in createStream
  File "/Users/MacAdmin/Documents/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/Users/MacAdmin/Documents/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.createStream.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:632)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
```

I run my program from command line as

```
/Users/MacAdmin/Documents/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.3.jar spark_streaming_sample.py
```

Do I need any environment variable or I am not using correct library versions?

Answer (score 0):

Few things were missing, added classpaths

```
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/:$PYTHONPATH
```

And spark logging is private from 2.* onwards so had to use below kafka streaming version while running program

```
spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.10-2.1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the topic created (**7T-test3**) in Kafka before executing the stream.

You may also want to provide more details leading up to the error.